# symfony1.4 I18nHelper.php not found

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I deployed my symfony 1.4 project from my local machine (Windows 7) to my test server (Linux Ubuntu Server).
Whenever I open this project through my browser (IE, FF...) I get an Error 500 which is most certainly caused due to an error which I get from the log/frontend_staging:

```
"symfony [err] {InvalidArgumentException} Unable to load "I18nHelper.php" helper in: SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/frontend/lib/helper, SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/helper, SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper."
```

The File `I18NHelper.php` is located in `SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper`, so I don't see a problem there. I already played with the naming, though some people mentioned they had trouble with the uppercase N in the Helpers name on Unix systems, but this didn´t solve my problem at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very nasty little thing:

Use `<?php use_helper('I18N'); ?>` instead of `<?php use_helper('I18n'); ?>` (Mind the upper case of the last 'n').

Linux is case-sensitive, unlike Windows.

Comment: I don't add the helper to each template but configured it globally in the settings.yml: `i18n: true` and `standard_helpers: [Partial, Cache, I18n]`. Changing the second I18n to I18N don't change anything, so there must be another thing I'm missing.

Comment: Did you clear the cache? If you look closely the exception says it's looking for `I18nHelper.php`, and you said the `I18NHelper.php` did exists in the helper folder (mind the capitalization of the N again)...

Comment: I know, the error message doesn't change no matter if I write I18N or I18n, it's always looking for I18n.

Comment: You could test your settings by renaming or symlinking the `I18nHelper.php` to `I18NHelper.php`. Just to validate settings. (Not recommended to keep in production for future updates).
I think somewhere still is a reference to the `I18n`...

Comment: This works as said in my answer, so symfony is always looking for the lowercase I18n. Don't know where to change it thought, even did a search through the whole project on I18n (case-insensitive) and didn't find any other occurance.

Comment: No, I'm quite sure it doesn't. I have multiple projects running on linux, without this issue. Could you go to `/cache/<app>/<env>/config/config_settings.yml.php` and check your setting there? If it's correct, can you display your full exception stack?

Comment: Ok, wow, we figured it out. For some reason we don't understand the frontend folder within cache was not writeable to symfony, so clear cache didn't clear the cache. I deleted the folder manually, changed i18n once again to I18N in the settings.yml, and now it's working. Don't know what happened there, this never happened before with any of our smyfony applications.

Comment: First of all `./symfony cc` should have thrown errors if there were problems with the permissions. But it's always advisable to run `./symfony project:permissions` after a deploy, to check all permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the helper's name The last "N" should be uppercase.

In templates it should look like:

```
<?php use_helper('I18N'); ?>
```

If you are modifying the settings.yml it should look like:

```
standard_helpers: [Partial, Cache, I18N]
```

You have to keep in mind that symfony YAML configuration files are cached as php files. If you don't clean your cache, your changes won't be applied (depending on the environment of course). Try using:

```
php symfony cc
```

from command line, it should fix it.

Comment: As said in the comments below, this doesn't help at all. Symfony always looks for I18n, no matter what's written in the settings.yml